# Problems with Solve. Only works for specific parameters. Solve function do not "start"

Tags: equation-solving, parameters

I have the following problem I want to solve the following equalities.

My used code:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
d = 0.75;
qa[ta_] = (ta)^(1/ya) - 1;
qb[tb_] = (tb)^(1/yb) - 1;
ya = 3;
yb = 2;
SOLCEQ1 = 
 Table[Solve[
   qa'[ta]/Log[d] (d^(tb + 1)/d^(ta) - 1) == qa[ta] && 
    qb'[tb]/Log[d] + qb[tb] == b qa[ta] && tb > ta && ta > 0, {tb, 
    ta}], {b, 0.8, 1, 0.1}]
```

The answer is:

```
{{{tb -> 4.45415, ta -> 2.50827}}, {{tb -> 4.57749, 
   ta -> 2.53496}}, {{tb -> 4.70672, ta -> 2.56222}}}
```

But if I now change (swap) ya and yb.

Code:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
d = 0.75;
qa[ta_] = (ta)^(1/ya) - 1;
qb[tb_] = (tb)^(1/yb) - 1;
ya = 2;
yb = 3;
SOLCEQ1 = 
 Table[Solve[
   qa'[ta]/Log[d] (d^(tb + 1)/d^(ta) - 1) == qa[ta] && 
    qb'[tb]/Log[d] + qb[tb] == b qa[ta] && tb > ta && ta > 0, {tb, 
    ta}], {b, 0.8, 1, 0.1}]
```

The answer is:

```
{Solve[-((1.73803 (-1 + 0.75^(1 - ta + tb)))/Sqrt[ta]) == -1 + Sqrt[
     ta] && -1 - 1.15869/tb^(2/3) + tb^(1/3) == 0.8 (-1 + Sqrt[ta]) &&
    tb > ta && ta > 0, {tb, ta}], 
 Solve[-((1.73803 (-1 + 0.75^(1 - ta + tb)))/Sqrt[ta]) == -1 + Sqrt[
     ta] && -1 - 1.15869/tb^(2/3) + tb^(1/3) == 0.9 (-1 + Sqrt[ta]) &&
    tb > ta && ta > 0, {tb, ta}], 
 Solve[-((1.73803 (-1 + 0.75^(1 - ta + tb)))/Sqrt[ta]) == -1 + Sqrt[
     ta] && -1 - 1.15869/tb^(2/3) + tb^(1/3) == 1. (-1 + Sqrt[ta]) && 
   tb > ta && ta > 0, {tb, ta}]}
```

So the programm do not start the Solve function process. I tried everything. If somebody knows a solution, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your claim "the programm [program] do [does] not start the Solve function process" is not true: the returned inputs mean the `Solve` cannot solve those and the message is performs. Making use of `NMinimize` instead of `Solve`, the following works in 13.3.1 on Windows 10:

```
Clear["Global`*"];d = 0.75;qa[ta_] = (ta)^(1/ya) - 1;
qb[tb_] = (tb)^(1/yb) - 1;ya = 2;yb = 3;
SOLCEQ1 =  Table[NMinimize[{(qa'[ta]/Log[d] (d^(tb + 1)/d^(ta) - 1) - 
    qa[ta])^2 + (qb'[tb]/Log[d] + qb[tb] - b qa[ta])^2, 
tb > ta && ta > 0}, {tb, ta}], {b, 0.8, 1, 0.1}]
```

> `{{5.44948*10^-21, {tb -> 7.05961,  ta -> 3.07779}}, {1.38056*10^-20, {tb -> 7.99239,  ta -> 3.19818}}, {7.22472*10^-22, {tb -> 9.06827, ta -> 3.30832}}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.